# php post value from FOREACH to another page

Tags: php, database, variables, foreach, hyperlink

I've never asked any question here before, but after spending many hours searching for a hint I decided to ask a question.

I have a project at school where I need to create a table from DB for all records for one user, and then create an expanded view for all details for a chosen record.

So far I have:

```
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypassword';
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass );
$sql = "
SELECT  id,login                                                                                                        
FROM quotes_taxi                                                                                            
WHERE login='[usr_login]'";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );                                                                           
$query->execute();                                                                           
$results
```

where 'id' is obviously ID for each record. Then I create a table using FOREACH

```
<?php foreach( $results as $row ){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'; echo $row['id']; echo '</td>';
echo '<td>'; echo $row['login']; echo '</td>';
echo '<td>'; echo '<a href="../view/index.php?id=$row['id']"> View All </a>'; 
echo '</td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

the problem I am having is: how can I attached that 'id' within the link (and it needs to be a separate button for each ID), so I can pass it to the view/index.php where I am using

```
$quote_id = $_GET["id"];
```

to get all other details of a chosen ID...

I know I have an error in that line, I just cannot figure it what. I also assume it is an easy problem, but I just cannot get my head around it

any help is most appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to separate your PHP and HTML that way it will be easier to find errors quickly. Try the following code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Login</th>
        <th>View</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['login']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="../view/index.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> View All </a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

**Output**

[image: foresch output]

Comment: that actually passes the ID:

    view/index.php?id=2017000011

Thank you for that. 

However, my view page does not seem to be recognizing that ID from URL. I am using simple 

    $quote_id = $_GET['id'];

and then the  $quote_id is used in WHERE statement for sql select. However, that does not seem to be working.

Comment: Doesn't matter... I am just being silly... all seems to be working now just fine.

Thank you very much for your help julekgwa!! Much appreciated

Comment: try to echo `$quote_id` to see if the value is there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this function

```
function AddGetParams()
{
    $linkParams="";
    foreach($GLOBALS["_GET"] as $key=>$value) 
    {
        $linkParams.="$key=$value&";
    }
    return $linkParams;
}
```