# insert variable into href in php not working

Tags: php, html

Been struggling with this for hours. Followed several similar examples I found online, none identical situation, and can't get it to pass the variable. I know it's basic, but just learning. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
        foreach($arr as $r) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$r['TimeStamp']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$r['LocationName']."</td>";
            **echo "<td><a href='details_get.php?id='$r['Post_ID']>".$r['Title']."</a></td>";**
            echo "<td>".$r['Price']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$r['Description']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
```

I added a variable $id to make the code clearer and easier to work with, but still can't pass the value.

```
<?php
        foreach($arr as $r) {
            $id = $r['Post_ID'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$r['TimeStamp']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$r['LocationName']."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='details_get.php?id='.$id.'>".$r['Title']."</a></td>";
            echo "<td>".$r['Price']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$r['Description']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
```

Finally got it to work, but I had to separate my php foreach loop and html as found in this post [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957714/php-post-value-from-foreach-to-another-page).

```
        <?php foreach($arr as $r) : ?>                
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $r['TimeStamp']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['LocationName']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="details_get.php?id=<?php echo $r['Post_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $r['Title']; ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Price']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Description']; ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Change the `$r['Post_ID']` like you did the title.

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, which is [totally fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), do it as an answer, not in the same question. Have a look at [ask] if you don't understand why.

Comment: Ok, thanks Raul Sauco, I will do that. Only my second question so still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 1):

```
        **echo "<td><a href='details_get.php?id='$r['Post_ID']>".$r['Title']."</a></td>";**
```

this row should look like

```
echo <td><a href="details_get.php?id=".$r['Post_ID'].">".$r['Title']."</a></td>";
```

You are missing a dot in the $r['Post_ID'] I think.

If you share more information may be I can give you others advises

Comment: You need the quote at the start of the `echo`.

Comment: echo "<td><a href=details_get.php?id=".$r['Post_ID'].">".$r['Title']."</a></td>";

Comment: @pedramshabani Almost, need to remove the single quote though because that closes the `href`.

Comment: Hi, wanna let you this answer @JulianMendez but you need to correct it, better use single quotes `'` for the PHP string, and maybe double quotes `"` for the HTML attribute values.